# Parse json and populate dropdown by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

this is my json return from server side mvc controller.

```
[{"Id":"AL","Name":"Alabama"},{"Id":"FL","Name":"Florida"},{"Id":"IA","Name":"Iowa"},{"Id":"MS","Name":"Mississippi"}]
```

this way i am trying to parse it and trying to populate dropdown by jquery.

```
 $(function () {
        $('#CountryID').change(function () {
            var dropdownID = $(this).val();
            $.post('@Url.Action("Index", "Home")', { CountryID: dropdownID }, function (result) {

                $("#State").html("");
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var item = result[i];
                    $("#State").append(
              $("<option></option>").val(item.Id).html(item.Name)
        );
                }
                //$('#State').html(items);
                $("#State").prop("disabled", false);
            });
        });
    });
```

a wired error is coming form jquery code that is as follow and capture by firebug console

```
TypeError: $(...).prop is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

..."Alabama"},{"Id":"FL","Name":"Florida"},{"Id":"IA","Name":"Iowa"},{"Id":"MS","Na...
```

i am not being able to figure out. so if possible please tell me what kind of mistake i am making in the code. thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery ?

Comment: jquery version jquery-1.5.1.min.js

Comment: There is no prop() in that version, you need to update as that is too old.

Comment: Use jQuery 1.9.1. The 1.5.1. version was released in Feb 2011. Upgrading it can only bring advantages ;)

Comment: change code into `$.prop ? $("#State").prop("disabled", false):$("#State")[0].disabled = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#State").prop("disabled", false);
```

change to

```
$("#State"d).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: problem solved after using this $("#State"d).removeAttr('disabled'); thanks